# monit configuration for php-fpm

Tags: php-fpm, monit

I'm struggling to find a monit config for php-fpm that works.

This is what I've tried:

```
### Monitoring php-fpm: the parent process.
check process php-fpm with pidfile /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
  group phpcgi # phpcgi group
  start program = "/etc/init.d/php-fpm start"
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/php-fpm stop"
  ## Test the UNIX socket. Restart if down.
  if failed unixsocket /var/run/php-fpm.sock then restart
  ## If the restarts attempts fail then alert.
  if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
  depends on php-fpm_bin
  depends on php-fpm_init

## Test the php-fpm binary.
check file php-fpm_bin with path /usr/sbin/php-fpm
   group phpcgi
   if failed checksum then unmonitor
   if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
   if failed uid root then unmonitor
   if failed gid root then unmonitor

## Test the init scripts.
check file php-fpm_init with path /etc/init.d/php-fpm
   group phpcgi
   if failed checksum then unmonitor
   if failed permission 755 then unmonitor
   if failed uid root then unmonitor
   if failed gid root then unmonitor
```

But it fails because there is no **php-fpm.sock**
(Centos 6)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I´m using the ping.path directive in php-fpm to check if it´s working...

and configured it on nginx.conf (i down´t know if it´s your setup)

```
location /ping {
    access_log     off;
    allow          127.0.0.1;
    deny           all;
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

On monit.d

```
check process php-fpm.www with pidfile /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
  group php-fpm
  start program = "/etc/init.d/php-fpm start"
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/php-fpm stop"
  if failed host localhost port 80 protocol http
     and request '/ping'
     with timeout 20 seconds for 5 cycles
     then restart
  ## If the restarts attempts fail then alert.
  if 3 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
  depends on php-fpm_bin
  depends on php-fpm_init
  depends on nginx
```

Comment: thanks. the only other thing I had to do was uncomment ping.path and ping.response in php-fpm.d/www.conf

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if nginx is down, monit will kill PHP-FPM, possibly making whatever problem you're having worse.

Comment: @Synchro - Check the last line on the monit.d script... ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could see, the only difference between php5-fpm and other processes (like nginx) is that its pid file doesn't contain a newline character. Maybe that's the problem. In any case, my solution is uglier but it also works nicely: I just check "process php-fpm with pidfile /var/run/php5-fpm.sock" directly (while trying to find a fix to this bug).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using monit's process pattern matching along with the existing daemon start and stop?

Some form of `matching "php-fpm"`

Comment: well it's already tracking the process from the pid file is it not? I was thinking the answer might be to open a http page and look for "bad gateway" - but no idea how to do that :s

Answer (score 0):

Is there `php-fpm.sock` file in `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`? If there is, then modify this line

```
if failed unixsocket /var/run/php-fpm.sock then restart
```

wit

```
if failed unixsocket /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock then restart
```

Comment: nope - no php-fpm.sock anywhere.